# UITableView load ONCE all cells in background

Tags: uitableview, swift3

Good day! Very simple question. 
I load custom cells in background with dequeueReusableCell 'cos I have images loading from url.

The problem is when I start to scroll. TableView synchronously starts to reload cells, so they "blink" with different content.

If I scroll slowly, it blinks and finally fills cells with the right content, but if I do it faster, it can shuffle content. It's funny to see, but it is still a problem,

I think the best solution is to load cells once and just scroll static table. Is it possible??

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if self.dialogs[indexPath.item].fromID == profileID {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "dialogMeCell", for: indexPath) as! CellForDialogMe
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let photoURL = self.partners[indexPath.item].userPhoto as! String
            let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string: photoURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!)!)
            let partnerPhoto = UIImage(data: imageData!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let partnerName = "\(self.partners[indexPath.item].userName!) " + "\(self.partners[indexPath.item].userSurname!)"
                var messageText = ""
                if self.dialogs[indexPath.item].hasAttachments! == true {
                    messageText = "Attachment"
                }
                else {
                    messageText = self.dialogs[indexPath.item].text!
                }
                if self.dialogs[indexPath.item].readState == false {
                    cell.message.textColor = UIColor.white
                    cell.message.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.561, green: 0.651, blue: 0.757, alpha: 1.00)
                }
                cell.fillWithContent(partnerPhoto: partnerPhoto!, partnerName: partnerName, message: messageText, selfPhoto: self.profilePhoto!)
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "dialogHimCell", for: indexPath) as! CellForDialogHim
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let photoURL = self.partners[indexPath.item].userPhoto as! String
            let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string: photoURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!)!)
            let partnerPhoto = UIImage(data: imageData!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let partnerName = "\(self.partners[indexPath.item].userName!) " + "\(self.partners[indexPath.item].userSurname!)"
                var messageText = ""
                if self.dialogs[indexPath.item].hasAttachments! == true {
                    messageText = "Attachment"
                }
                else {
                    messageText = self.dialogs[indexPath.item].text!
                }
                if self.dialogs[indexPath.item].readState == false {
                    cell.partnerName.textColor = UIColor.white
                    cell.message.textColor = UIColor.white
                    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.561, green: 0.651, blue: 0.757, alpha: 1.00)
                }
                cell.fillWithContent(partnerPhoto: partnerPhoto!, partnerName: partnerName, message: messageText)
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to cache your images.  You only make the asynch request if the image is not in your cache.  If you have the image in the cache then just show the cached image.  While you could just hold a dictionary of [String : UIImage] and use the URL's as keys, this isn't very memory friendly or bandwidth friendly since its not persisted.  You can write a much more sophisticated cache, but other people have already done it so I suggest just using one of theirs: [SDwebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) [AlamofireImage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage)